# Why are destructured environment variables undefined in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, next.js

In my Next.js app I've created a `.env` file with a variable named `API_KEY`.

Destructuring the value results in `undefined`, as shown here:

```
const { API_KEY } = process.env; // = undefined
const key = process.env.API_KEY; // = 'value'
```

Can someone please explain why `process.env` isn't populated with the correct value here?

Comment: Remove the  ```{}``` and try again. ```{}``` are used when there are multiple imports

Comment: @HimanshuSaxena This doesn't explain why node result is undefined. This is es6 usage - using destructuring and otherwise works on everything else.

Comment: Can you show the actual code you tried? I mean you used some console.log, right? Or how do you know the api_key is undefined? Can you create minimal example which proves this?

Comment: Both lines should work the same. How exactly are you running this script? In what environment? How do you load the `.env` file? Are you using a transpiler/build pipeline?

Comment: @Bergi I am using Next.js. My console.log is in my react component.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables):

> Note: In order to keep server-only secrets safe, Next.js replaces `process.env.*` with the correct values at build time. This means that `process.env` is not a standard JavaScript object, so you’re not able to use object destructuring.

and for client-side React components

> The value will be inlined into JavaScript sent to the browser because of the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix. This inlining occurs at build time, so your various `NEXT_PUBLIC_` envs need to be set when the project is built.